# Can i download a Google map on computer as PDF from A to B for offline viewing

Tags: download, google-maps

I want to go somewhere and i want to download the whole route with direction as pdf .
Is it possible

Answer (score 5):

Your best bet would be to use a PDF printer like [CutePDF Writer](http://www.cutepdf.com/Products/CutePDF/writer.asp) (free). It installs as a printer on your Windows computer, and then you can print the directions in Google Maps straight to the CutePDF printer, which will let you save the file as a PDF.

[image: Google Maps image]

Comment: But i want to download the magnified version of map not just one small image

Comment: You can click the blue **Maps** link at the top of the page to show a small map for each step of the directions. Checkmarking the **Include large map** at the top (just to the left of the Print button) will show a large map of the whole trip in the print out.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using OSX, just [select PDF from the print dialog](http://clc.its.psu.edu/Labs/Mac/help/software/howtocreatepdfs.aspx) and you can save a PDF to your computer.

Answer (score 0):

For saving webpages for later reading, I use the [ScrapBook](http://amb.vis.ne.jp/mozilla/scrapbook/) Firefox plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You might also give this wed site a go at it:
http://www.web2pdfconvert.com/Default.aspx

Comment: Be advised that spammers have referred to this website in the past, so I'm not 100% willing to trust this.